# Evaluating $\iint_D\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ln(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy$ using polar transformation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

> Evaluate $$\iint_D \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ln(x^2+y^2) \, dx \, dy$$, where $$D = \left\{(x,y):\frac{1}{4}\leq x^2+y^2\leq1,x^2+y^2\leq2x,y\geq0\right\}$$

I tried solving it by changing to polar coordinates but I can't find the interval for the polar angle.
At all, can someone explain me how to find the interval for the polar angle and the polar radius? Every time I solve problems with polar change I can't find the right intervals.

Comment: are you sure about polar coordinates? Note that $x^2+y^2\leq2x$ is difficult to express in polar coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The inequality becomes $r\leq2cost$ if $r$ and $t$ are the polar radius and the polar angle respectively

Comment: Well, I mean that $r \le 2 \cos t$ is not the most comfortable condition to work with, but it may work.

Comment: Any ideas how to continue? The problem is from the polar coordinates section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Result**

The integral can be calculated exactly to give

$$i = \frac{5}{72} (\log (8)-4) \simeq -0.133372\tag{1}$$

**Derivation**

Transforming to polar coordinates $x\to r \cos(\phi)$, $y\to r \sin(\phi)$, $dx dy = r dr d\phi$ the integral becomes

$$i = 2\int r\sin(\phi) \log(r)\,dr d\phi$$

The restrictions transform to polar coordinates as follows

$$\frac{1}{4} \le x^2+y^2\le 1 \to \frac{1}{2} \le r \le 1\tag{2a}$$

$$x^2+y^2\le2x \to 0\le \phi\le \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)\tag{2b}$$

so that we have

$$i = 2 \int_ {\frac{1}{2}}^1 r \log(r) \int_{0}^{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)} \sin(\phi) \,dr \,d\phi$$

or, doing the $\phi$-integral,

$$i = 2 \int_ {\frac{1}{2}}^1 r\left(1-\frac{r}{2} \right) \log(r)\,dr$$

The final $r$-integral gives $(1)$. QED.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me intuitively how to know that this is the only restriction for the polar angle? Because I have that it lies in the first quadrant.
And can I draw the polar coordinate system like the Cartesian one and see visually what is going on and find the limits for the angle and radius?

Comment: You can express condition (2b) as $(x-1)^2+y^2\lt1$ from which and $y\ge0$ you can see that the integration region is in the first quadrant and is given by the union of the ring of inner radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and outer radius $r=1$ and the unit circle centered at $(1,0)$. The rest is inverting $r\lt 2 \cos(\phi)$.

Answer (score 1):

The limits are difficult to calculate due to the $x^2+y^2\le 2x$ however without limits it is of the form:
$$I=\iint r\sin\theta\ln (r^2)drd\theta=2\iint r\sin\theta\ln|r|drd\theta$$
which is easy enough to solve once you have worked out the limits

Comment: Can I draw the polar coordinate system $O\theta r$ like the Cartesian coordinate system $Oxy$ with two perpendicular lines and then find the limits of $\theta$ and $r$?

Comment: Rewrite $x^2+y^2\le2x$ as $(x-1)^2+y^2\le1$ and you can see the regions more clearly. I have given the complete soluton in my answer.